# How to call some script on onDeviceReady function in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I am very newbie on `jquery-mobile` programming.Beside this,I am developing a android app from `jquery-mobile`. I need to call some code on `onDeviceReady` function. Code need to be call is :

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.init("5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
                           {googleProjectNumber: "703322744261"},
                           app.didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack);`
```

---

Also I need to call this code under didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack function

```
didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack : function(jsonData) {
    alert("Notification received:\n" + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
}
```

These code need to be implemented on `index.html` of my `jquery-mobile` project.
Waiting my answer ASAP...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using phonegap, based on that, you'll need this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    //mycode
});
```